# Solving the biharmonic equation $\square^2f(\vec{x}) =0$ on a curved space

Tags: spacetime, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, curvature, differential-equations

How to solve the [biharmonic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biharmonic_equation) $\square^2f(\vec{x}) =0$ on a curved space (e.g. $d$ dimensional sphere or hyperboloid)?

I was thinking in the following line : I know how to solve $\square f(\vec{x}) =0$. On sphere the solution should be given by spherical harmonics. So suppose the solution is $f^0_{sol}$, then to get the desired solution one needs to solve the following DE,
$$\square f(\vec{x}) = f^0_{sol}(\vec{x})$$

Couldn't make this work.

Comment: By "curved space" do you mean a space with _uniform_ curvature?

Comment: Yes. For simplicity let's take maximally symmetric space.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?